# How to remove blank data in Bar chart in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, format, bar-chart

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to remove the first bar (Blank) from the bar chart and the data label will recalculate the % by excluding the blank data. The reason why there are some blank data is because there are some data missing for some students. The DAX formula that I used to categorized the students into different % group is:

```
RankCategory =

VAR CatVar=[Success_Rate] 

RETURN CALCULATE (VALUES ( BenchMark[Category]), CatVar>BenchMark[Lower_Level],CatVar<=BenchMark[Upper_Level])
```

May I know how should I modify in my Bar chart or modify the DAX formula so that it can achieve my goal? Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a **visual level advance filter** as shown below-

[image]

Comment: I tried to did exactly what you did, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: It is okay right now, I changed it to Basic filtering and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method to suppress the NULL bars in Power BI:

1. Click the visual
2. Select the paint icon on the left
3. Change the X axis to "**Categorical**"

[image]